# Estimate probabilities of independent events given constraints

Tags: regression, logistic

Suppose we have a dataset with various variables $\{X_1, X_2, ...\}$ with unknown distributions, and a binary response variable $K$ that is a direct function of one of the $X_i$'s. Let us say an indicator function. Suppose further that we want to estimate the probability that $K = 1$ and that we want the following two constraints to be fulfilled:

1. The sum of $P(K = 1)$ for the entire dataset equals the number of elements with $K = 1$;
2. The sum of $1/P(K = 1)$ for the subset with $K = 1$ equals the size of the dataset.

1 is fulfilled automatically by logistic regression, so that seems like a good candidate. But what about 2? Is there anything one can introduce to a logistic regression routine that would make it fulfill 2 as well? Or must one look elsewhere for appropriate methods?

Comment: Can you tell us the motivation for your condition 2)?

Comment: So that the estimated probabilities behave as sample inclusion probabilities. K is a sample inclusion indicator.